# wp-admin vs wp-login in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Any ideas on the difference between https://mysite/wp-admin vs https://mysite/wp-login?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share further details as to exactly what you're asking?

Comment: They are two different URLs that both allow you to login to the dashboard. I was wondering why wordpress chooses to have both routes. Seems insecure.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting down voted. I can't find an answer anywhere. Why even have the second URL if all it does is redirect?

Answer (score 7):

Actually both URLs will let you login into your site's dashboard.

However, they are different:
While *wp-login* (which should be *wp-login.php*) is a php file in the root folder which returns the form to login into your WordPress, *wp-admin* is one of the three default folders (*wp-admin*, *wp-content* and *wp-includes*) which contains internal files such as libraries and scripts.

So, if you haven't logged in yet, by going to *wp-admin* you will be redirected to *yoursite.domain/wp-login.php?redirect_to=...* If you are already logged in, by going to *wp-login* it will show you once again the form to access, and *wp-admin* will take you directly to your dashboard.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

wp-admin redirects to wp-login.php. I.e. there is only one admin log in page.

Comment: I believe wp-login.php redirects to wp-admin.php

Answer (score 0):

Both of these URLs will redirect to the WordPress login page. If your 'wp-login' url is not working properly you can use another one 'wp-admin'.